# wsimport command fails with error

Tags: java, soap

I have a WSDL file copied to my personal system.  When I run wsimport using the following command, I get the error 'Missing WSDL_URI'

```
wsimport -keep -verbose -p com.somecompany.somegroup.someservice -wsdllocation C:\affinity\AffinityGroupInquiry_2_PROD.wsdl
```

I have tried running this with multiple jdks.  The command failed with JDK 1.5 and 1.6 from IBM, and 1.7 from Oracle.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Command looks correct. Maybe your wsdl file is corrupted/contains `include` with wrong URL?

Answer (score 4):

The syntax in my command was actually wrong.  The documentation clearly shows that we should list the path to the wsdl at the end of our command, and that users should not use the -wsdllocation flag.  Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Wrong:

```
wsimport -keep -verbose -p com.somecompany.somegroup.someservice -wsdllocation C:\affinity\AffinityGroupInquiry_2_PROD.wsdl
```

Right:

```
wsimport -keep -verbose -p com.somecompany.somegroup.someservice C:\affinity\AffinityGroupInquiry_2_PROD.wsdl
```